# 'Value' is an invalid attribute for 'xsl:text'

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm working with the following XML & XSLT and am getting an error related to an undeclared attribute. I've tried a few methods of declaring the attribute 'Value', but am still getting some variation of the error "'Value' is an invalid attribute for the 'xsl:text' element.

Thoughts on how to correct this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GLPayrollExportConfiguration>
  <definitions>
    <FileType Value="CSV"/>
    <FileName>
      <Value Value="CRJ_GL_Summary_"/>
      <Value Value="paygroup_xref"/>
      <Value Value="_"/>
      <Value Value="payrun_payperiod_and_suffix"/>
      <Value Value="_"/>
      <Value Value="transaction_timestamp"/>
      <Value Value=".csv"/>
    </FileName>
    <Settings>
      <SplitMode Value="HOME_LOCATION_SPLIT"/>
      <ChartOfAccountXRefCode Value="GL"/>
      <RunOnPayRunCommit Value="True"/>
   </Settings>
   <!--
    <Header>
      <Text Value="Posting Date,"/>
      <Text Value="Document Type,"/>
      <Text Value=" ,"/>
      <Text Value="Account Type,"/>
      <Text Value="Account No,"/>
      <Text Value="Fund No,"/>
      <Text Value="Dimension Speedkey Code,"/>
      <Text Value="Dimension 1,"/>
      <Text Value="Dimension 2,"/>
      <Text Value="Dimension 3,"/>
      <Text Value="Dimension 4,"/>
      <Text Value="Dimension 5,"/>
      <Text Value="Dimension 6,"/>
      <Text Value="Dimension 7,"/>
      <Text Value="Dimension 8,"/>
      <Text Value="External Document No,"/>
      <Text Value="Description,"/>
      <Text Value="Amount,"/>
    </Header>
    -->
    <Columns>
      <Column Name="PostingDate" DataType="datetime" Source="data" Value="payrun_pay_date" Sort="true"/>
      <Column Name="PostingDate1" DataType="datetime" Source="data" Value="payrun_pay_date"/>
      <Column Name="DocumentType" Value=" "/>
      <Column Name=" " DataType="string" Value="PAYROLL"/> 
      <Column Name="AccountType" DataType="string" Value=" "/>
      <Column Name="AccountNo" DataType="string" Source="data" Value="payrun_category_override_journal_number"/>
      <Column Name="FundNo" DataType="string" Value="UNREST"/>
      <Column Name="OnSiteLedgerCode" DataType="string" Source="data" Valye="override_segment_charged_dynamic_org_level_onsitedepartment"/>
      <Column Name="LaborMetricCode" DataType="string" Source="data" Valye="override_segment_dynamic_labor_metric_code_CostNumber"/>
      <Column Name="Dimension1" DataType="string" Value=" "/>
      <Column Name="Dimension2" DataType="string" Value=" "/>
      <Column Name="Dimension3" DataType="string" Value=" "/>
      <Column Name="Dimension4" DataType="string" Value=" "/>
      <Column Name="Dimension5" DataType="string" Value=" "/>
      <Column Name="Dimension6" DataType="string" Value=" "/>
      <Column Name="Dimension7" DataType="string" Value=" "/>
      <Column Name="Dimension8" DataType="string" Value=" "/>
      <Column Name="ExternalDocumentNo" DataType="string" Value=" "/>
      <Column Name="Description" DataType="string" Source="Data" Value="payrun_category_override_description"/>
      <Column Name="Amount" DataType="number" Source="data" Value="payrun_amount" Function="sum" />
    
    </Columns>
  </definitions>

  <MappingDefinitions>
    <definition>

    <criteriaset> 
<!-- EXCLUDE MEMO DEDUCTIONS AND TAXABLE BENEFITS / JOURNAL NUMBER CODED AS exclude, Exclude, or EXCLUDE  -->   
        <criteria item="payrun_category_override_journal_number" op="ne">EXCLUDE</criteria>
        <criteria item="payrun_category_override_journal_number" op="ne">Exclude</criteria>
        <criteria item="payrun_category_override_journal_number" op="ne">exclude</criteria>
<!-- EXCLUDE RECORDS WITH with 0 VALUE -->
        <criteria item="payrun_amount" op="ne" opDataType="number">0</criteria>
    </criteriaset>

    <mapping>
        <mapto columnname="DimensionSpeedkeyCode">
          <Value Value="override_segment_charged_dynamic_org_level_onsitedepartment"/>
          <Value Value="override_segment_dynamic_labor_metric_code_CostNumber"/>
        </mapto>        
        <mapto columnname="Description">
          <Value Value="payrun_category_override_description"/>
                  
        </mapto>        
    </mapping>
    
    </definition>   
  </MappingDefinitions>

  <ColumnFormats>
    <ColumnFormat Name="PostingDate" Format="MM.dd.yy"/>
    <ColumnFormat Name="PostingDate1" Format="yyyyMMdd"/>
    <ColumnFormat Name="DocumentType"/>
    <ColumnFormat Name=" "/>
    <ColumnFormat Name="AccountType"/>
    <ColumnFormat Name="AccountNo" WrapChar="&quot;"/>
    <ColumnFormat Name="FundNo"/>
    <ColumnFormat Name="DimensionSpeedkeyCode" WrapChar="&quot;"/>
    <ColumnFormat Name="Dimension1"/>
    <ColumnFormat Name="Dimension2"/>
    <ColumnFormat Name="Dimension3"/>
    <ColumnFormat Name="Dimension4"/>
    <ColumnFormat Name="Dimension5"/>
    <ColumnFormat Name="Dimension6"/>
    <ColumnFormat Name="Dimension7"/>
    <ColumnFormat Name="Dimension8"/>
    <ColumnFormat Name="ExternalDocumentNo"/>
    <ColumnFormat Name="Description" WrapChar="&quot;"/>
    <ColumnFormat Name="Amount" Format="{0:##.00}"/>
  </ColumnFormats>
  
 </GLPayrollExportConfiguration>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:cs="urn:cs" exclude-result-prefixes="xs">

  

  <msxsl:script language="C#" implements-prefix="cs">
    <msxsl:using namespace="System.IO"/>
    <![CDATA[

            
        public static int DayDifference(string rehiredate,string termdate)
        {       
            String rehire=rehiredate;
            String term=termdate;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(rehiredate)==true || string.IsNullOrEmpty(termdate)==true) return 0;
                DateTime d1 = DateTime.Parse(rehire.Substring(6,4) + '-' + rehire.Substring(0,2) + '-' + rehire.Substring(3,2) );
                DateTime d2 = DateTime.Parse(term.Substring(6,4) + '-' + term.Substring(0,2) + '-' + term.Substring(3,2) );
            return (d1 - d2).Days; 
        }   
        
        public static int DayDifferenceSys(string rehiredate)
        {       
            String rehire=rehiredate;
            DateTime CurrentDate= DateTime.Now;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(rehiredate)==true) return 0;
            DateTime d1 = DateTime.Parse(rehire.Substring(6,4) + '-' + rehire.Substring(0,2) + '-' + rehire.Substring(3,2));
            return CurrentDate.Subtract(d1).Days;
        }   
        
        
        public string DateAdd(string s1,int i){
            DateTime d1= DateTime.Parse(s1.Substring(6,4) + '-' + s1.Substring(0,2) + '-' + s1.Substring(3,2));
            
            return d1.AddDays(i).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            
            
            }
        
            
            
       ]]>
  </msxsl:script>

  <xsl:output method="text"/>
    
  <xsl:template match="/">
  
    <xsl:text Value="Posting Date,"/>
    <xsl:text Value="Document Type,"/>
    <xsl:text Value=","/>
    <xsl:text Value="Account Type,"/>
    <xsl:text Value="Account No,"/>
    <xsl:text Value="Fund No,"/>
    <xsl:text Value="Dimension Speedkey Code,"/>
    <xsl:text Value="Dimension 1,"/>
    <xsl:text Value="Dimension 2,"/>
    <xsl:text Value="Dimension 3,"/>
    <xsl:text Value="Dimension 4,"/>
    <xsl:text Value="Dimension 5,"/>
    <xsl:text Value="Dimension 6,"/>
    <xsl:text Value="Dimension 7,"/>
    <xsl:text Value="Dimension 8,"/>
    <xsl:text Value="External Document No,"/>
    <xsl:text Value="Description,"/>
    <xsl:text Value="Amount"/>
    
    <xsl:for-each select="Export/Record">
    
        
            <xsl:value-of select="PostingDate"/><xsl:text>,</xsl:text>          
            <xsl:value-of select="DocumentType"/><xsl:text>,</xsl:text>     
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('PAYROLL',PostingDate1)"/><xsl:text>,</xsl:text>       
            <xsl:value-of select="AccountType"/><xsl:text>,</xsl:text>      
            <xsl:value-of select="AccountNo"/><xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="FundNo"/><xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="OnSiteLedgerCode != ''">
                    <xsl:value-of select="OnSiteLedgerCode"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="LaborMetricCode != ''">
                    <xsl:value-of select="LaborMetricCode"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="DimensionSpeedkeyCode"/><xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="Dimension1"/>         <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="Dimension2"/>         <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="Dimension3"/>         <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="Dimension4"/>         <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="Dimension5"/>         <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="Dimension6"/>         <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="Dimension7"/>         <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="Dimension8"/>         <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="ExternalDocumentNo"/> <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(PostingDate,' ',Description)"/><xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="Amount"/>
        
        
    </xsl:for-each>
    
    
    
    
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `xsl:text` instruction takes no attributes other than `disable-output-escaping`  and can contain only character data.

To create literal text, use:

```
<xsl:text>Your text here</xsl:text>
```

To generate computed text (e.g. copy the string-value of a node), use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="SomeNode"/>
```

You can also generate literal text as:

```
<xsl:value-of select="'Your text here'"/>
```